# How do I allow a user approve a task from the email?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email

In our project the managers receive emails with their tasks. The new requirement is to allow the managers to approve their tasks from the emails. Near every tasks is an "Approve" button that should be added to allow approvals of tasks without going to the site of the company.

How do I do it?

Comment: What mail client are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that without going to the site? I'm afraid that is not possible. At least, in cross-"email client" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, that is not possible. Most email clients will never run javascript, so you can't use ajax to call your server.

Another option - iframe with a form to set an approval in it. According to [this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/) in some email clients it will work. In others - no.

As for me, the most realistic way is to put a simple link. Click on it will open browser, of course, but you can make that page close itself after everything is done.

The last option I see is to send an email to some specific address, like approve_task@company.com with subject containing an ID of a task and establish listener which will check email received by approve_task@company.com and mark task as approved. No problem to make a mailto: link in email body. But you can't send any emails automatically. Managers will need to click it and send an email manually. So I do not think this is really good solution.

Comment: FAngel, thank you for your help! Did you see the comment option for Picasa in GMail. How do they do it?

Comment: I do not use picasa. But gmail and picasa are both google products and I do not think it was hard for them to implement some special feature. At the same time - you can always see how it is done with dev tools and check if it works in other email clients, like outlook, windows live hotmail, thunderbird etc.